# Python Not Callable Error With scipy.integrate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am getting a not callable error when trying to use a Gaussian Quadrature integater in python. I have defined my list prior to when I am trying to update it and I am lost as to what is causing the error.

I tried out the same, but with a different function to integrate, and got a float is not callable error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
solD = odeint(SolveMe, ic, t) # Solution to ODE
solT = np.zeros(partition)

for i in range(partition):
    solT[i] = integrate.quadrature(solD[i:,1], 0, 6)

-----------------
Error in Console:
-----------------

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Is solD a function?

Comment: Per the documentation, the first argument to [scipy.integrate.quadrature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html) must be a function.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to python and was obtuse to what the error meant. I was able to fix it after a while. Thank you!